# Android App doesn't connect to webserver PHP file

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have a problem with my Android app locating or connecting to the PHP file on the webserver.

The code:

```
try {

            URL url = new URL(register_url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            bufferedWriter.write(encodedStr);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            os.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

I checked many times the register_url is correct.
When launched manually the PHP file successfully connects to the database.

Comment: Are you getting an error message or ...?

Comment: Have you run if in a debugger?  If so what exception/error do you get?  If none, check the server logs and see if you connected to the server or not (to figure out what side the problem is on).

Comment: @GabeSechen Thank you for replying. Everything is working fine, the problem wasn't with the connection. I was reading and writing data in wrong way.